# How to Secure a string from UserInput

Tags: c#, string, security, xss

We have a Website where a user can reject something from another user with a reason. The reason is sent to the other user via email.

What characters can be sent to the other user?
I am not going to do a regex search for unwanted characters but rather only want to keep "potentially" "safe" characters in the reason.

For example the reason:

```
"Hello <b>Dear User B"
```

Would be transformed to:

```
"Hello bDear User B"
```

Currently i'm just doing a "Where" on the char array and define my "safe" conditions via

```
char.IsLetterOrDigit || char.IsPunctuation || char.IsWhiteSpace
```

Are there any better techniques?

Comment: I don't see the difference between "Hello Dear User B" and "Hello bDear User B" except for the nonsense bDear in the second item.

Comment: your question is unclear, kindly rephrase it.

Comment: @hacktick ah your edit made the point clear.

Comment: +1 for the user name alone :()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perfectly fine use HTML in email body. This will allow for prettier formatting. You could use the [AntiXSS library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) on the user input before sending it by email to filter dangerous things out of the HTML (things like `<script>` tags for example).

Comment: I bet, though, that AntiXSS is complex enough that it opens its own new security holes :O

Answer (score 1):

you could try using the HttpEncoder class in C# with the htmlEncode method on your string.
This will turn all < > into the html equivalent of &lt ; etc. Returning a safe string.

Though it will look ugly with all the &lt ; and kinda-like-stuff in the email, you could see it as a potentially safe-work around.

If you are inserting the comments into a database as well I wouldn't recommend using this method, as it's not sql-injection proof. In that case you can use the htmlencode for sending emails and use parameters with inserting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

if you think characters having ascii value 32 to 126 are safe for you, Then you can use

```
bool bad = value.Any(c => c < 32 || c > 126);
```

Comment: this wouldn't support chinese or other languages that have "letter characters" outside of that ascii value bound. but otherwise this would be a good enough starting approach for a non international apps in the western hemisphere.

Comment: I was not expecting Chinese characters..:D

Comment: @hacktick - Come up with a requirement, edit your question, and we can help you.  Changing the requirement to support the chinese language is unfair.